# Curvature of Lie group endowed with bi-invariant Riemmanian metric.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras, curvature

Let $G$ be a Lie group endowed by a biinvariant Riemmanian metric $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ and $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra.
It is known that the metric is fully determined by its behaviour at the identity element, i.e. the scalar product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_e$ on $T_eG\cong\mathfrak{g}$.

Now, the following properties hold for the curvature $R$, Ricci tensor $Ric$ the Killing form $B$ , at the identity element, i. $\forall x,y,z\in\mathfrak{g}$:

1. $R(x,y)z=\frac{1}{4}[[x,y],z]$
2. $R(x,y,x,y)=\frac{1}{4}||[x,y]||^2$,
3. $\operatorname{Ric}(x,y)=-\frac{1}{4}B(x,y)$

Now, I agree that the same relations will hold when evaluating the corresponding tensors on the unique left invariant vector fields $X,Y,Z$ determined, respectively by $x,y,z$.

But the sources presenting these results then use them to say that, for instance the sectional curvature is nonnegative or, if $G$ is compact and semisimple $(G,-B)$ is Einstein. I mean this would certainly be true if we could extend this relations to hold for any vector field, and not only for left invariants one. And I don't see why this should be true.

What am I missing?

Comment: $R$ and $\operatorname{Ric}$ are bi-invariant tensor fields, so their behavior on $\mathfrak{g}$ completely determines them.

Comment: Ok, so at any point $p\in G$, for any vector fields $X,Y\in\chi(G)$, no matter it is leftinvariant, we have for instance $Ric(X_p, Y_p)=Ric_e((dL_{p^{-1}})_pX_p,(dL_{p^{-1}})_pY_p)$ and we are done? Can I deduce they are biinvariant just observing they are defined in terms of the (biinvariant) Levi Civita connection of a biinvariant metric? Or is there some difficulty lurking in the bushes?

Comment: More or less. Another way of putting it is that left/right translations are isometries, and $R$ and $\operatorname{Ric}$ are isometry invariant.

Comment: You're dealing with tensors, and every $v \in T_gG$ can be written as $v = X_g$, where $X$ is left-invariant.